# Copy user-control without serializing

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, copy, clone

I know there is so many reference about copy an `object` by `Clone()` . but I didn't find a useful reference about copying a `Control` which isn't serializable! :(

I have a `Panel` and it has some controls in it. I want copy this panel completely.

Could u please help me to find a good and easy solution for it! :)

THX

**ANSWER**

I created a `UserControlContainer` by [How to make a UserControl object acts as a control container design-time by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813450)

then u should insert [this code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b426e182-c6d1-4c8f-8bc0-194613e2be6e/how-to-copyclone-a-populated-user-control) to `UserControlContainer`.

it seems there is no shorter way :|

Good Luck

Comment: There is no simple way to do that.  Put it into a UserControl and create multiple instances.

Comment: You don't "copy" the UI because UI is not data. Try copying your data instead. BTW, if you're using winforms please tag your question `[winforms]`. Not everybody is using such a deprecated technology these days.

Comment: @SLaks it's hard for me to create an UserControl, because I've never done it... :(

Comment: Right-click, Add New Item, User Control.

Comment: @HighCore what do u mean about `data` ?! each control have some props and in my `Panel` there is some controls too!! u know what am i say :(

Comment: if you don't know the difference between `UI` and `Data`, you're going to have a hard time getting your software to work properly.

Comment: @HighCore `UI` is user interface and `Data` is its contains :D I'm a learner and take it easy my friend ;)

Comment: @SLaks I did it. but I don't know why I can't insert my panel in `UserControl`

Comment: @SLaks if know please help. I have to go to sleep. Good night

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: @SLaks Hi! u said I use `UserControl`. I did it but the location of `panel2` change by loop and don't create new one. what should i do?

Comment: @SLaks what am I waiting for?! just waste a time for some ones offer. wish I didn't gave u votes

Comment: No.  You should move all of that UI to the UserControl, so that you can make a copy by creating another instance of the UserControl.